# SMS Library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sms

Anyone know of a free SMS library or webservice for .NET that will allow me to send text messages to people's cell phones?

Answer (score 2):

What are you looking for actually? a Library or a Proxy?

a **Library** is just an API that you can program to in a user-friendly way... that, there are hundreds out there, because that you need to add all the payed proxies, they all give you an API to program to.

If you are talking about **Proxies**, 98% of the proxies out there are not for free, and you need to pay a monthly basis amount of per SMS sent, it's up to you. All of them have trial versions (for example 100 SMS that you can send for free... normally called Credits).

There is some open source projects for SMS proxies, but for the Linux world like [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/news.shtml).

You can **make your own** using COMM interface and have a old mobile with a card that you can send commands to and make your own API interface based on that (there are plenty of SMS free packages and you might have it as well in your country)

for now... try this link:

> http://email2sms.ru/sms.php

and a nice but old article on how to send sms using your own phone:

> http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/wireless/2003/10/10/sms.html

Answer (score 2):

Try [bulksms](http://www.bulksms.com/), very cheap and provide an incoming and outgoing service in pretty much every country for local SMS rates.

Answer (score 1):

ReadWriteWeb

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/zeep_mobile_free_sms_gateway.php

Answer (score 0):

Clickatel and most other SMS gateway providers provide some trial credits. And some service providers provide Email2SMS conversion. i.e You can send an email to +94xxxxxxx@yourprovider.com and it will be sent as an SMS.

These information does not answer your question directly but they would be useful in your taks..

Answer (score 0):

Use a SMS provider like clickatell. Sending a SMS is just a matter of sending a correct HTTP GET request containing your account information, the message and the recipient. See: http://support.clickatell.com/guides/clickatell/api_guide.php.

From .NET, you simply use the `System.Net.WebClient` class to create a correct HTTP GET request. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a pretty good one called PennySMS. It has a pretty good and simple web service I can consume and seems to work with all different types of cell phones.